# Live Kali LInux stuck at Dragon Logo on shut down, or restart

Tags: linux, boot, shutdown, iso-image, kali-linux

I made a live Kali USB drive using Rufus and Kali Live ISO (I am using Windows 11). When I boot using USB on my laptop, the OS although starts slowly but still boots up. But after I restart or shutdown, it does not shut down, and is stuck in the dragon logo, and I have to manually press hold the power button to power off.

## Things I have tried

- Used

> kali-linux-2023.2-live-everything-amd64.iso

, as well as

> kali-linux-2023.2-live-amd64.iso

.

- Made USB drive using ISO as well as DD format.
- Made Persistent storage using Rufus, as well as using guide available in Kali Linux's website(https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/usb-persistence/).
- Booted Kali Linux in the normal mode, as well as in the Persistent Storage mode.
- Although gedit was not installled already. I updated using `sudo apt-get update` and installed gedit using `apt-get gedit`. And then used `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub/` to delete quiet-splash, but the file opened was empty.
- Tried two pendrives, one with USB 2.0, and one with USB 3.1.
- I have checked the checksum as well with the website, and they match of the iso files.

All of these things did not change the outcome, and the boot time was also not much different between USB 2.0 and USB 3.1, but one time when I booted using USB 2.0 and Persistent Storage, the boot was very slow and step wise, like after the dragon logo disappeared and the "-" sign appeared and then when it disappeared, the top taskbar appeared, and then the desktop wallpaper and desktop files appeared. Every step took a solid, 5 min.

PS - The changes I made were not saved even when I booted using Persistent storage. Maybe because of the forced shut down.

Comment: The answer I posted about Kali running on a Windows 11 machine was correct. The downvoter should feel obliged to post a better answer.

Comment: @John Not really. I remember seeing it and it had lots of wrong assumptions.

Comment: You cannot run Kali on a box that have Secure Boot enabled. It will not start. I tested it.

Comment: And that is absolutely IRRELEVANT. SB can be disabled to run anything else and re-enabled to run the installed Win11. And if the only issue is it being stuck on shutdown **of a live session** is that really a problem?

Comment: And, of course, because https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/ we all should understand that users whom "should" be running Kali won't be asking questions here. So, NOT answering trivialities is a way to make certain people understand that helping kids steal their neighbours' WiFi is NOT what most volunteers here are up to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147665/discussion-between-john-and-changanauto).

Comment: @john I am sorry, I am not able to follow your discussion here. Is there anything wrong with the question ?

Comment: Your question could be a little more focused but it is clear enough. What I answered was that you cannot start Kali directly on a Windows 11 Production machine because Kali will not start when Secure Boot is active. I have tested this.

Comment: My Secure Boot is off. I have previously used dual boot, Mint, and Ubuntu with Win 10 and 11, in the same laptop.

Comment: In theory it should start. I use the bare metal Kali, not the live version. I had to, on some weekly Kali downloads, attach the disk to the SCSI controller and that may be causing you an issue.

Comment: I don't know about attaching the disk to the SCSI controller, could you please elaborate. But I sure did followed the official guide for this live boot.